# Laravel Validation fails when passing data through ajax Request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am passing the value of the radio button to the controller when it is selected through ajax. The validation in the controller fails saying the field is required. I logged the dataString which carries the value in `beforeSend`. It logged the value of the selected of radio button. I also checked the network tab's requests which has the data in the request payload. I don't understand what causes the error here.

```
<input type="radio"  name="port_type" id="low-risk" value = "low-risk" >

if ($('#low-risk').is(":checked")) {
    var p_type = $(this).val();
    console.log(p_type);
    showFunds(p_type);

}
```

Here is the function that has ajax function

```
    function showFunds(p_type){
        var hello = p_type;
        //console.log(p_type);
        var dataString = 'p='  +hello;
        //console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/showFunds",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend : function(){
          console.log('logging BS');
          console.log(dataString);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(xhr ,status ,error)
        {
            console.log(xhr);
        },

        });
      }
```

Here is my controller

```
 public function showFunds(Request $request){

        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'p' => 'required',
            ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            //return response()->json(['msg'=>'val_fail']);
            return response()->json(['msg'=>$validator->errors()]);
        }

        else{ }
```

The validator failing sending the errors **"The p field is required."**

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: no errors in the console @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Inside your `showFunds` put `print_r($request->all())` and check if some value is present in `p` or not?

Comment: no data is present inside the array when `print_r($request->all());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function showFunds(p_type){
    var hello = p_type;
    //console.log(p_type);
    var dataString = JSON.stringify({p: hello});
    //console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/showFunds",
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend : function(){
      console.log('logging BS');
      console.log(dataString);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(xhr ,status ,error)
    {
        console.log(xhr);
    },

    });
  }
```